# How to determine a rhombus knowing its center and the two slopes of its sides in analytic geometry

Tags: analytic-geometry

I am new to coordinate geometry.
I am not able to solve this question, as I have no idea, from where to start.

Question:

Two sides of a rhombus $ ABCD $ are parallel to the lines $ y = x+2 $ and $ y=7x+3 $ . if the diagonals of the rhombus intersect at the point $ (1,2) $ and the vertex $ A $ is on the $ y $ - axis , find possible coordinates of $ A $ .

Comment: the vertex or one vertex is on the y- axes?

Comment: @Dr. Sonhard It was a blunder, sorry. Take a look again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A(0,a)$ and $E(1,2)$.

Thus, $m_{AE}=2-a$ and we obtain:
$$\left|\frac{2-a-1}{1+(2-a)\cdot1}\right|=\left|\frac{2-a-7}{1+(2-a)\cdot7}\right|.$$
I hope you could end it now.

Comment: @Jean Marie It was my delirium. Thank you! I think now it works.

Comment: I understand also that I was wrong thinking that the solution is not unique.

Comment: @Jean Marie We can get two solutions exactly, which says that one of quadratic equations has no real roots. I checked it. It's indeed, so!

Comment: There are indeed two solutions (see my answer), not more.

Comment: @Jean Marie Yes, I got exactly these numbers.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg Can you tell me name of some books which you used to study class 11 and 12 ?

Comment: @Maanav Roy In Israel all school's books they are very bad. I myself am a book.

Comment: @Micheal Rozenberg Then how did you learnt geometry? Any book's name?

Comment: V.V Prasolov "Problems.", A.V. Akopyan "Geometry in pictures".

Answer (score 2):

(see figures below representing the two solutions).

Let the vertices $ABCD$ be taken in the direct (trigonometric) orientation. Let $I$ denote the rhombus' center.

The equations of the lines with the given slopes passing by $A(0,a)$ are :

$$y-7x-a=0 \ \ \text{and} \ \ y-x-a=0$$

Let us recall that the distance of a point $P(x_0,y_0)$ to a straight line L with equation $ux+vy+w=0$ is

$$\tag{1}\text{dist(P,L)=}\dfrac{|ux_0+vy_0+w|}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}$$

A necessary and sufficient condition of "rhombusity" (!) is that diagonal $AI$ is the angle bissector of angle between $AB$ and $AD$, i.e.,

$$\text{dist(I,AB)=dist(I,AD)}$$

Thus, using (1), we need to solve the following equation:

$$\dfrac{|y_0-7x_0-a|}{\sqrt{1^2+7^2}}=\dfrac{|y_0-x_0-a|}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2}} \ \text{with} \ (x_0,y_0)=(1,2)$$

This gives $|-5-a|=5|1-a|$, out of which one gets two solutions

$$a=0 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ a=2.5$$

[image]

[image]

(Figures representing the two cases $a=0$  and $a=2.5$)

Comment: I also got these numbers. +1.

Comment: I have added a second figure.